# Security concerns when using Google Firebase notifications instead of VPN

Tags: security, firebase-cloud-messaging, vpn

It might be heretical idea but please bear with me, it's not my expertise. 
I'm using an app that communicates with AWS lambda. I want lambda then to communicate with other comp. Instead of using classic VPN, I'm thinking if I could use firebase notifications. So lambda would send notification to other computer, which would do some stuff (open locker) and return response.
Is this safe (enough) considering that in locker there can be semi valuable stuff?

Comment: Unless that other computer is running Android, iOS or a web browser, you won't be able to target it with FCM.

Comment: yes, this part is obvious but would it make sense as Lambda in VPN comes with cold start + other costs?